# Check if variant is Null or an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic range that is being used to set a combobox in vba.

The range starts as `A3` (which will contain nothing to start) and goes all the way to `A3:A9999`, depending on how many elements are in the range.

The code then pulls in the data from the range and stores it in a local variant.

My code in VBA is this:

```
If tempj <> Null Then
    cmb_JobNum.List = tempj
End If
```

When there are 0 elements in the array, `tempj = Null`, so it does not attempt to set the list.

When there is 1 element in the array, `tempj =  [Value of cell]`, so it will set the list to that single element.

When there is 2 or more elements in the array, `tempj` is now an array, so trying to equate it to a single element throws a 'type mismatch' error. I have no clue how to update the code so that it doesn't get caught out by that error, since every time that equate is run it will crash.

Comment: Can you use a dynamic named range in the sheet and then use that as your list source?

Comment: Use the `IsNull()` function to check for null, not `<>`.

Comment: The Problem with using `IsNull()` is that, while it is a better choice for function, it doesn't fix the issue in which trying to add 2 or more items to the list causes the type mismatch. I ended up using a `VarType()` method to check whether it was a string or array, and then use an appropriate function to add to the list. I have posted my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
If VarType(tempj) <> 0 Then
    If VarType(tempj) = 8 Then
        cmb_JobNum.AddItem tempj
    Else
        cmb_JobNum.List = tempj
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(tempj) To UBound(templ)
    cmb_JobNum.AddItem tempj(i)
Next
```

This code will loop through your array and add every element in it to the combobox. Thus, if array is empy, then no elelements will be added, when there's >0 elements, then all of them will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a dynamic named range to set the fill

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6") '<== change as appropriate
        .ComboBox1.ListFillRange = .Range("dynRange").Address
    End With

End Sub
```

`dynRange` formula added via name manager (Ctrl + F3)

```
=OFFSET(Sheet6!$A$3,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet6!$A:$A),1)
```

---

**Using a worksheet change event to automatically update the combobox:**

You could tie this into a Worksheet_Change event on the range A3:A9999 to update automatically the Combobox.

If tying to an event in the code pane of the sheet containing the combobox you could have the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A9999")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("dynRange").Address
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Example code run:**

[image: Test run]

**Code pane for sheet containing Combobox:**

[image: Code pane]

---

**Note:**

This is assuming an ActiveX combobox but can easily be update for a Form Control ComboBox.

For a form control swop out lines and use:

```
 With Shapes("Drop Down 2").ControlFormat '<== change to appropriate name
     .ListFillRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("dynRange").Address
 End With
```

Edit: For UserForm combobox you can populate in the initialize e.g.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cb1.RowSource = Sheet1.Range("dynRange").Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Any feedback at all?

Comment: Unfortunately your method didn't work for me either. I did end up being able to get it working and posted an answer. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Well done on figuring out a solution. Regarding mine:  I had throught you didn't know whether you would have one item or several (passed in as an array) from the sheet. What about the above doesn't work please so I can update the answer for future readers?

Comment: Well the way my solution works is by checking what type of variable it is, and then assigning the list based on that, so that way a single value or an array can be added without throwing an error. With your solution, I couldn't quite figure out how to get it working entirely in a userform

Comment: Ok. Thanks for getting back to me :-)